# Getting "error generating report. Unknown print order 0" error during calling JasperFillManager.fillReport method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jasper-reports, tomcat5.5, subreport

I'm working on a *Java EE* application, with *Java 6*, *Dynamic Web Module 2.4*, *Tomcat 5.5* and *MySQL 5.5*.

We are using *JR* reports, designed with *iReport*. All of them work properly but one. The strange thing is that this report worked ok before, and we didn’t change anything in the code… (configuration problem?).

When we execute the report, the error is this:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:500)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:407)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:308)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

And the console say this:

```
error generando informe Unkown print order 0.
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Unkown print order 0.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.initSubreportFiller(JRFillSubreport.java:390)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:359)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluate(JRFillSubreport.java:260)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:275)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:426)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:1380)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:692)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:255)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:113)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:888)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:810)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:89)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:601)
    at com.tsystems.web.ModuloInformes.InformesNuevos.InformeGestion.Actions.InformeGestionAction.generarReporte(InformeGestionAction.java:1655)
    at com.tsystems.web.ModuloInformes.InformesNuevos.InformeGestion.Actions.InformeGestionAction.generarInformeGestion(InformeGestionAction.java:222)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:270)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:187)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at com.tsystems.web.common.FiltroSeguridad.doFilter(FiltroSeguridad.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:879)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The action (Java method) that execute the report is this:

```java
    private void generarReporte(List info, InformeGestionFormBean gestionBean, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String descripDispo) {
        try {
. . . 
            InputStream is = null;
            String header = "";
            is = informeGestionAction.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(ruta + "InformeCuadroGestion.jrxml");          

            header = "attachment; filename=\"InformeCuadroGestion";

            JRExporter exporter = null;
            JasperReport reporte = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(is);          
            JasperPrint jasperPrint;
            JRBeanCollectionDataSource datos = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(info);

            jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, parametros, datos);
```

The error comes when `JasperFillManager.fillReport` is called.

Report’s XML code is:

```xml
<field name="bloqueInforme1" class="java.util.List"/>
<subreport  isUsingCache="true">
<reportElement  x="0"   y="6"   width="782"height="10" key="subreport-1"positionType="Float"/>
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{bloqueInforme1})]]></dataSourceExpression>    
<subreportExpression  class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "PDFInformeCuadroGestionSub1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
</jasperReport>
```

We have followed ***bloqueinforme1*** values during the Java code. ***bloqueinforme1*** is a *List* with *Lists* inside with the info for the report, and we have seen that the values are correct. The error seems to be in the subreport that the main report uses.

I’ve been focused on a field (example ***Item***) that is part of ***bloqueinforme1***. We can print and get Item value correctly but when we execute the report only using ***Item***, the report says that it can’t find Item.

We don’t know the error cause; maybe is the *List* of *Lists* (it can’t find the sublists); or a configuration problem (we had to change *Dynamic Module* from *3.0* to *2.4*).

Please, I am desperate! Can you help me?

---

I am very sorry! The error on my first post was not the initial error.The initial error is this:

```
Could not load object from location : ..\..\iReport\PDFInformeCuadroGestionSub1.jasper
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Could not load object from location : ..\..\iReport\PDFInformeCuadroGestionSub1.jasper
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObjectFromLocation(JRLoader.java:271)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:311)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluate(JRFillSubreport.java:260)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:275)
```

We have a lot of reports working fine. The only one that fails is the only one with subreports. when I compile the report (including subreports) with iReport, it compile ok, so I think is not a compilation problem.
Our app generetes .japer files during runtime. This report worked fine before, but now...
The path we use as a parameter to specify the place to generate the report and subreports, I mean .jasper files, is a relative path: ../../iReport. I tried absolute paths like, but when I try this path:

```
C:/Documents and Settings/Administrador/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/phnemos_ph/iReport/
```

I get this error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.net.MalformedURLException
```

I'm working on thisa problem since weeks ago.. I need help, everything you can tell me would be great. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Did you check this report with small console application? Is it working?

Comment: You need to get full stack trace.

Comment: Did you compile the subreport and pass it to the master report?

Comment: The subreport compile properly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I feel might be because of the $P{SUBREPORT_DIR} variable.
Why don't you pass the sub-report.jasper file as <"DATA_SOURCE",jasperreport file> as hashmap in fill manager.fillreport's 2nd paramter.
Create a parameter field in main report as DATA_SOURCE.
your data source expression seems fine.

Comment: In the xml file the expresion is:<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{bloqueInforme1})]]></dataSourceExpression>
     <subreportExpression  class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "PDFInformeCuadroGestionSub1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>

Comment: The expression seems fine. As I mentioned the problem is may be in  $P{SUBREPORT_DIR}. I'll tell you what I did while accessing .jasper files. I placed them in build path and accessed them as JasperReport  sub_report=(JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(this.class.getResourceAsStream("/filename.jasper"));

Answer (score 0):

Hello again and thank you for all suport.

I want to report something important.
When I chage the header in the jrxml file from:

```
<!DOCTYPE jasperReport PUBLIC "//JasperReports//DTD Report Design//EN" "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/dtds/jasperreport.dtd">
```

to

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
```

I get again `Unknown print order 0`

Thanking you very much

Comment: Is this an advice "To not do the same" or this is a new question?

Comment: The problem is solve. When I change the header in th jrxml file, update the jasperreport library. And update some tags. The report work properly!!!

Comment: Thanks you very ver very much!!!